# Managing input data with googlesheets in a website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to work on this little project for my dad at school because he is a teacher and needs my help...
Anyways the little program that I'm trying to write in html css and javascript is going to be hosted to a domain soon when its finished.
I also have 3 columns in Googlesheets that I want to link to the website
The first column would have "Student laptop name" the 2nd column "laptop serial number" 3rd column "student name".
So its basically a normal page with an input and button element, where students can type their laptop names. So what we want to achieve is :

1. Students type their laptop name in the input element in the website, and then after hitting submit I want to run a code that searches in a whole googlesheet column to find a match for the name or value of input. If the laptop name matches then we want to load a whole new html page that says Welcome + student name + laptop serial number
   Example : Student types, Lenovo legion y750, then run a script that searches the whole laptop name column for Lenovo legion y750 lets say The lenovo legion y750 was found on column A25 and next to it there is B25 with the student name and C25 with student serial number. So if the name matches then we want to load a new html page that says Welcome +  The string on the same row in Column B which would be student name + serial number from column C.
   Please note that the database of students is almost 50k.

Please help me I've been trying to achieve this for so long and I've looked all over and found that I can use NodeJS with googlesheets api but I dont know if I can change css using nodejs and it gets so complicated..

Comment: hello, what about turn your sheet into a database to easly deal with ? and have you begin something ? it's more simple to help you on a code bases

Comment: I have the data in a txt file and like I said its almost 50k students, do you advise me to write 50k lines of code in javascrip?

Comment: haha so funny, not , just to fill a database of your choice  with your 50k entries and after it will be more simple to write a script to acheive your goal , by this way it will be esiar too add the new student each year too

Comment: what i mean is instead of just make a script you can build a whole program that can be verry useful and simple to add features after (sorry for my sad english ^^)

Comment: That's sound good, do you have any ideas of what programming language I can use?

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: @HisokaMorrow can you tell me more about your web dev skill ? like that i can recomand you to make a react app coupled with firebase database but it just beacause it's what i know

Comment: The Idea of using Google Spreadsheet as a database is a good idea.  You can then use either Form or HTMLService to present a form for the use to fill out and populate the database with their response.  Other functions can be written in App Script to filter, sort, add/remove data with you or your dad as the database administrator.  Getting 50K lines of student info into a Spreadsheet should be relatively easy using CSV parser or even just text parser.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Just to show how easy it is to develop a database and user interface for something like your request, I put together a simple web app that can do what you describe in your question.

First I have a Google Spreadsheet Sheet1 with the data for your laptops.

[image]

Next I develop an HTML page to get the laptop name and display the results.  I can run either from Spreadsheet or web app.  I'm using an HTML Template to seperate the HTML, CSS and Javascript into seperate files.

And I include the app script code to tie everything together.  I add a menu item to run from Spreadsheet and the `doGet()` to run a web app from the browser.  For the web app you need to deploy the project as a web app and then simply give the user the url link.

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('CSS_Test'); ?>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="textLaptop" type="text">
    <input id= "buttonLaptop" type="button" onclick="buttonLaptopOnClick()" value="Get">
    <br>
    <input id="textStudent" type="text">
    <br>
    <input id="textNumber" type="text">
    <?!= include('JS_Test'); ?>  
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS_Test.html**

```
<style>
  #textLaptop {
    font-size: large;
  }
</style>
```

**JS_Test.html**

```
<script>
  function buttonLaptopOnClick() {
    try {
      let laptop = document.getElementById("textLaptop").value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
        function (student) {
          document.getElementById("textStudent").value = student[1];
          document.getElementById("textNumber").value = student[2];
        }
      ).withFailureHandler(
        function (msg) {
          throw msg;
        }
      ).getLaptop(laptop);
    }
    catch(err) {
      alert(err); // doesn't always work but most of the time
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Show Test", "showTest").addToUi();
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test").evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function showTest() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test").evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Test");
}

function getLaptop(laptop) {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1QQ...YourSpreadsheetIdHere...q4");
  let values = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();
  let student = values.find( row => row[0] === laptop );
  if( student.length === 0 ) throw "Laptop ["+laptop+"] not found";
  return student;
}
```

**Web App.**

I've shown the custom dialog but the web app will appear similar.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**Refernces**

- [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#index.html)
- [HTMLService Best Practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)
- [google.script.run()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)